# Change Safari language setting? (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, safari, language

When I bought my MBP Safari worked fine and it's default language was En but after I added Farsi as my second Language Safari now uses my Farsi setting and show all text in RTL (because in Farsi I write from right to left). How can I change Safari's default language back to English?

I read [this](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=6889371) but it's not a proper solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a freeware, [Language Switcher](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/), to launch single applications with a different language.

To remove not needed languages of an application, there is Monolingual (.sf.net) and similar apps.

Comment: It's a nice application and work for me, thank you for your answer but I also need a solution that can easily can config in Os X without any extra application.

Comment: You can drag the languages in
System Preferences -> Language & Text -> Language
in your desired order.
OS X uses the first language, applications will be launched in the first available language.
In general, check "Languages & Text" for appropriate settings.

Comment: yep, :D this work it's a tricky solution tanx.