# Safari picked wrong spell checker

Tags: macos, dictionary, input-languages

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Canadian English on Apple products](https://superuser.com/questions/153725/canadian-english-on-apple-products)
>   [Change Safari language setting? (Mac OS X)](https://superuser.com/questions/167554/change-safari-language-setting-mac-os-x)

I bought MacBook Pro lately from Cambridge, UK, so I expected my language preference to be set to British English. But when I'm typing in Safari it suggests me American English spellings.  For example, when I type `Colour`, it asks me to correct it to `Color`!

How do I change language preferences and dictionary in Mac OS X?

Comment: Almost exact duplicate of [Canadian English on Apple products](http://superuser.com/questions/153725/canadian-english-on-apple-products) (just a different variant of English). Also check out [Change Safari Language Setting](http://superuser.com/questions/167554/change-safari-language-setting-mac-os-x) for how to change it for just Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Language & Text preferences:

[image: lang & text]

If British English isn't there, click Edit List… and add it:

[image: british english]

Then drag it to the top. You might also want to change stuff in the Formats & Input Sources tab.